# Start up circuit in power supply independnent biasing

Tags: simulation

I simulated the start up circuit in a power supply independent biasing. I know that the start up circuit is there to makes sure that there is current fllowing thought the transistors preventing the degenerated bias condition but how does this actually work ?? and what sense can I make out of the simulation ??

This is my circuit,

[image]

and this is my simulation result (And the current is in Pique amps)
[image]

Comment: I'd need the voltage scale for the vertical axis as well. I've got a hunch, but I'm not going to say unless i can confirm against the voltage graph.

Comment: The voltage scale is in Volts. The blue line being the supply goes to 3.3 V , the yellow line approximatelly to 2 V and the gate voltage given to MN7 is at 0,48 V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. You've not designed the start up transistors properly. You have a tie that doesn't belong there, and you need to resize some things.
[image: Wildar]

I had thought that there might be some shenanigans with the power supplying only enough voltage to get the transistors into linear region. Then I noticed that odd current had no reason to be there. Please redesign your circuit and re-simulate.

Comment: Okay , Ill surely simulate it in the lab tomorrow ! From the circuit that you have given I can intuitively understand the following: Since the start up is to prevent the current from not being 0, I initially assumed that current I2 is 0 to see how the startup prevents this problem. So when I2 is 0 PMOS M6 is on and M5 off.Which means M7 is on. Since M3 is diode connected and M7 is on current must flow from M3 to M7. and since M4 is a mirror the current must thus also flow across M4, thus developing a drain source voltage across M2 and thus turning off M6. Is this undersanding correct ?

Comment: You're confusing currents with voltages, but the basic sequencing is correct. When the Voltage at M2 drain is zero, because there's no current I2, M6 turns on. This turns on M7 which turn on the pmos, forcing the mirror to go to the stabilized non-Zero solution. I believe this only works because of sub-threshold conductance characteristics in M2, but it's been a while since I last used this mirror in Virtuoso.